# how to add frame in graphicsview and set layout?

Tags: qt, qt5

I am creating graphics-view in which i play videos in each graphic-view.1X1,2x2,3x3,4x4. These are options. Now I want to add frame in which I want to add pushbuttons in each graphics-view and finally set layout for each
Please help me.

Comment: Please provide some (self-contained, as short as possible) code you tried and tell us what does not work.

Comment: To embed a widget in a scene, use `QGraphicsWidget`. For more information, please fix your question to let us know what specifically do you have a problem with. Create a minimal `main.cpp` test case that shows where you get stuck. Functional Qt applications can be very minimal, you don't need a `.ui` file, no header files, everything goes into a single `.cpp` file that doesn't even need to declare any classes. You can build and run the whole ui (parent widget, layout, children, etc.) in the body of `main()`.